# Autocompletion not working in Atom for C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can get autocomplete suggestions for words already entered in a project but not for unity keywords on first use, nor the api suggestions that are offered apparently in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete alone will only suggest words that you already wrote yourself. You can add more suggestions using packages.

Right now many people recommend using [OmniSharp](https://atom.io/packages/omnisharp-atom).
Unfortunately didn't work quite well for me, so i used [my own package](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-unity) but is far from good.

Comment: I solved the problem by switching to sublime text which has a unity completions add on already

Comment: Oh great! If you don't mind me asking, how is it? Using sublime is close enough as using Visual Studio or MonoDevelop? (for Unity projects)

Comment: I cannot comment on a comparison, I will never used any MS products and do not trust mono enough to use it either. Apparently the ST completions work differently, maybe not as good, but are good enough for me.